# phalanger (PHP): calling nested static C# classes

Tags: c#, php, phalanger

I cannot seem to get this to work without the compiler yelling at me for being... stupid. But I have a class with another nested static class inside of it. I am trying to access it but I get a syntax error saying:

```
unexpected token ::
```

I am trying to call the class as follows:

```
myLibrary\myClass::nestedClass::myFunction()
```

The first set to '::' work just fine but the second pair are causing an error. Any idea of how I approach this? A lot of my libraries are written this way and I would very much appreciate if someone could help me!

Comment: Aren't nested classes considered `private`, making the double-use of the SRO (`::`) invalid?

Comment: Hmmm, good point. Is there a way to get around this by any chance? The library is written in C#, so they aren't actually private...

Comment: Write a public function within *myClass* that calls the desired function from *nestedClass* (I'm assuming it's `static`)

Comment: Sigh, I was hoping I didn't have to modify the class itself. Ok, I guess ill just have to have a wrapper class that does some rewiring.

Comment: That's just one solution; there may be others out there, but I try to avoid writing nested classes in the first place.

Comment: Phalanger uses standard PHP namespace separator in order to access nested classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually a solution to this. Silly me! In order to get the nested class out of the class, its really simple. Look at how you can get a DataTable class out of the System .NET class:

```
  System\Data\DataTable
```

the same can be done with your library. For the code I have posted above, simply do:

```
  myLibrary\myClass\nestedClass::myFunction()
```

I replaced the first :: with a \ This way the compiler knows what I am looking for! Thanks for the suggestions, all of them would work wonderfully, in fact maybe are a little better code practice wise!

Comment: Yes, since PHP does not have nested classes, Phalanger developers had to specify how to access them. In PHP '::' operator accesses static members, and it would be performance and implementation overhead to use it to access nested classes. Classic PHP namespace separator was chosen instead.